# LINQ query causes System.NotSupported

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I got a list of Hero Ids and am trying to do a LINQ WHERE IN statement to retrieve all objects from database when their ID matches one in list.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("HeroList")]
public IHttpActionResult GetHeroList(HeroIdListModel model) {
if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Model invalid");
    List<Guid> heroIds = model.Ids;

    // check each Id is there
    heroIds.ForEach(o => { Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());});


   try
   {
    // WHERE IN Linq statement
    var heroes = db.Heroes
                    .Where(o => heroIds.Contains(o.Id))
                    .ToList();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            throw;
   }
    return Ok(heroes);
}

public class HeroIdListModel
{
    public string HeroTypes { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> Ids { get; set; }
}

public class Hero 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever i run this it throws the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

There is absolutely no other error or message in log that will enable me to debug this.

What could i be doing wrong?

**EDIT: Further Information**

1. Using Entity Framework 6
2. Using Visual Studio 2017 (inbuilt SQL Server)
3. "Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" is the only thing displayed nothing else
4. The code is exactly as in my project only thing omitted is logic that populates heroIds which is tested to be working
5. Debugger output

   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-131377605294445115): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-HeroServer'. 
   'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-131377605294445115): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'. 
   Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
6. Classes and complete method added

Comment: There's a lot of things that could cause this. Incorrect mappings and unexpected extension methods are the first two that come to my mind. What does your C# `Hero` class look like? What does your context class look like?

Comment: @Kris This exception means the generation of the SQL query failed, so no, the OP won't be able to print the generated query.

Comment: Is there any more information on the exception? Can you catch it and inspect its other properties?

Comment: Try this library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mshwf.NiceLinq/ 
like so: 
`db.Heroes.In(o => o.Id, heroIds).ToList();`
I see it less verbose than the `Contains` method, and more alike the SQL `IN` operator

Comment: If this throws an exception so would this `Where(o => o.Id == someGuid)` (where `someGuid` is a guid defined before the statement). What I mean is it is probably an exception unrelated to the code you have shown so far as it should be supported unless you are not telling us something like you are using a very old version of EF (which I doubt). For further help please **post the complete exception and all its inner details**.

Comment: @Igor I agree that it is very likely the case, but I really have seen `Contains` being re-implemented as an extension method for other container types, where EF then throws because that custom extension method is not supported, only .NET's `Enumerable.Contains`/`Queryable.Contains` are supported. :)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I think we all agree that a query that appears this simple should work, so we're looking for some reason why it doesn't. Could you give the _full_ definition of your `Hero` class, the schema for your Hero database table, and the code that would go between the definition of the list and your query?

Comment: "There is absolutely no other error or message in log that will enable me to debug this." -- If you only log the exception type, then yeah, that's going to happen. What does your debugger say? That should allow you to inspect in more detail, most importantly getting the exception message text.

Comment: @hvd that is from the debugger hence my difficulty to figure out way to approach this. Happy to make any modifications to my setup to get more out of debugger. Added further information

Comment: @Aeseir At the very least, you should be able to get a stack trace. You may need to tweak your debugger settings though. If all else fails, put an explicit `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { throw; }` around your code, set a breakpoint on the `throw;`, and inspect `ex` in your local variables.

Comment: @hvd tried that, same result. Frustrating :(

Comment: @Aeseir That's impossible. Even in the unlikely event that `ex.StackTrace` would be `null` or `""`, that fact itself would already provide additional information. Even in the unlikely event that `ex.StackTrace` cannot be accessed at all, precise details of what happens when you try to access it would provide additional information.

Comment: @Aeseir If you're in debugging mode, and something like this happens (https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC808492.jpeg) you should be able to click "View details" at the bottom under "Actions" and get more individual properties of the exception.

Comment: Do you do anything special on OnModelCreating of your db context? How is that set up?

Comment: @Aeseir Also, just to be _absolutely_ sure, can you stick `if(heroIds == null) { throw new Exception("heroIds is null"); }` before the query.

Comment: @Alex not touched anything there, default setup when web api was created

Comment: @BenJenkinson i got a foreach statement that iterates and prints each Id. Definietly not null.

Comment: Ok, wild guessing @hvd, do we know for sure that Visual Studio 2017's built-in SQL database/linq-provider (which was a flat file in some past version?) supports `Contains` over a GUID column? I mean, I'd be surprised if it didn't, but I can't think of any reason why this isn't working.

Comment: @Aeseir, I know you've tried to log the Exception to the console, but are you sure you're getting absolutely nothing when run your program in Debugging mode, and then place and inspect a breakpoint like this: http://i.imgur.com/27qJLu2.png

Comment: @BenJenkinson i would love to say that i dropped the ball and missed it but unfortunately no. This has been bugging me for 2 days now.

Comment: I'm suspicious of this `Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'` - what aren't you showing us in your code?

Comment: @Alex as i am relatively new to .NET (coming from Java world) i been learning. That could be due to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api that i followed.

Comment: is `Hero` tied to your identity stuff in any way?

Comment: @Alex The `EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies` thing is normal for EF. It generates a class that derives from `Hero` and/or other entities and overrides virtual properties (none in `Hero`) to implement lazy loading and/or change tracking. All types need to be in an assembly. EF names it `EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies`.

Comment: @Aeseir Silly question, but have you checked that the exception is coming from the place you've put the `try`...`catch` around? I'm thinking now that perhaps it's not coming from there, but from the code running after `return Ok(heroes);`. You'd be able to check this by returning some dummy value instead of `heroes`.

Comment: @hvd yep i stepped into it during debugging. It chucks a spaz at db.Heroes.Where() line.

Comment: @Aeseir Okay, and that's what you put the `try`...`catch` around that prints the exception. What exactly gets printed?

Comment: @hvd basically as i step through once it hits the Where() line, it goes to the catch(). It then prints exactly what i put there in the Output window. I really wish i was making this up :(. I am tempted to reinstall VS2017 and import the project again to see whether a dll has failed or something.

Comment: @Aeseir That helps: the Output window isn't usually where `Console.WriteLine`'s output goes. I guess you don't see anything with `Console.WriteLine("Hi!");` either? If you don't have a console window, and aren't redirecting your process's output to a file, that explains why you're not seeing anything. In Debug mode, you can use [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) to write to the Output window. But what I meant initially was to use the Autos/Locals windows to inspect the exception, without need to write additional code.

Comment: @hvd I used Trace as well as Debug.WriteLine. Autos/Locals don't show me anything. I even used Watche window. I'll reinstall, reimport and try again.

Comment: @hvd yes, I know - but the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` is the part i was questioning.

Comment: @Alex Ah, sorry, misunderstood (and misread). Still not too surprising, it's a library using Entity Framework too, so classes defined in there equally get proxies created for them. It's used to authenticate and authorise web requests, so it makes sense that it gets loaded prior to the execution of the OP's own web methods, and it makes sense that it's the last thing logged before the exception. But you have a good point: it's worth ruling out the problem being in there. An empty web method would do it: check whether that executes successfully.

Comment: Just a update for all. I uninstalled VS2017, cleaned the folder. Installed again and imported project. Works fine now. Thank you to all for your patience and support

Answer (score 0):

Issue seemed to be due to VS2017.

After going through all possible combinations and debug steps only option was to reinstall.

1. Uninstall VS2017
2. Clean projects folder (any any cache or relating folder you have)
3. Install VS2017
4. Import project

After which it worked without a problem.